# MuleSoft Maven Build Failure Using TFS Build Release

Tags: maven, tfs, maven-plugin, tfsbuild, mulesoft

We are using TFS GIT and trying to build the project and getting below error (the same code works fine on my local when i do mvn clean install but fails in tfs server):

Unresolveable build extension: Plugin org.mule.tools.maven:mule-maven-plugin:3.3.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to collect dependencies at org.mule.tools.maven:mule-maven-plugin:jar:3.3.5 -> org.mule.tools.maven:mule-packager:jar:3.3.5 -> org.mule.tools.maven:mule-classloader-model:jar:3.3.5 -> commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.6: Failed to read artifact descriptor for commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.6: Could not transfer artifact commons-io:commons-io:pom:2.6 from/to central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): Failed to transfer file http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-io/commons-io/2.6/commons-io-2.6.pom with status code 501 -> [Help 2]

2020-07-01T16:27:19.7473940Z org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginManagerException: Plugin org.mule.tools.maven:mule-maven-plugin:3.3.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to collect dependencies at org.mule.tools.maven:mule-maven-plugin:jar:3.3.5 -> org.mule.tools.maven:mule-packager:jar:3.3.5 -> org.mule.tools.maven:mule-classloader-model:jar:3.3.5 -> commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.6

Comment: Are you using a private agent? If so, does the private agent have a network route to the URL? Does traffic need to go through a proxy? What steps have you taken to troubleshoot the issue?

Comment: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2 will not work anymore since January https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/360041287334-Central-501-HTTPS-Required.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with khmarbaise.

I encountered into the same problem when I used Central Repository with http communication.

To solve this issue, you need to change the reference of Central Repository in the `Pom file` to `https` communication.

For example:

```
<Project>
 ....
     <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>central</id>
            <name>Central Repository</name>
            <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <releases>
                <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
            </releases>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>central</id>
            <name>Central Repository</name>
            <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
....
</project>
```

Then the Maven task could work as expected.

Hope this helps.